# Trying to concatenate all UUIDs from a given column to a single text value

Tags: string, postgresql, uuid

I'm trying to code the following stored procedure -

```
Create or replace FUNCTION concat_group_ids()
    RETURNS TEXT
    AS $function$
DECLARE
curs_group_ids CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM ad_groups;
result TEXT;
id UUID;
BEGIN
 OPEN curs_group_ids;
LOOP
    FETCH curs_group_ids INTO id;
    result = result || id;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        EXIT;
    END IF
END LOOP;
CLOSE curs_group_ids;
return result;
END; $function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But the concatenation of the id to the result does not work.
I get an empty result when running `select concat_group_ids();`

Comment: If there wasn't a result (NOT FOUND), you shouldn't concatenate what's in `id` with `result`.  Move the test before the concatenation operation.  If `id` is NULL ever, it will zap the value in `result` to NULL too (definition of `||`), which might explain your result.  I'm not sure if the value of `result` is initially NULL or an empty string (there is a difference, at least in some DBMS); that too might be a factor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have also tried during my tests to perform the following  -  result = result || 'a'  - and I did not get a string that loks like 'aaaaa.... " but an empty (or NULL) string. thanks

Comment: Try `result = '';` before the loop.  Also, do you really want the UUIDs all smushed together with no spaces?  Just something to think about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , of course not. I have tried something like result = result || ',' || id  prior to my post here. I am looking to see some results, after that I will finetune.

Comment: Fair enough; try assigning a string to `result` before appending to it.  If the empty string doesn't work, try a single blank, or something distinctive like `@` or `=` or `#`.  I'm guessing, of course; a semi-educated guess, but still guessing.